# Silicone use to bond wood boards at high temperature?

Tags: woodworking, adhesive, silicone, composite

I'm in a composites manufacturing class, and I'm looking to make a one-off carbon fiber mountain biking handlebar from prepreg.

As I don't want to invest in the metal needed to make a proper mold, I'm experimenting with using quarter-sawn oak to hopefully prevent too much warping with the heat. I need to glue some of the boards together to get a thick enough mold, and the mold has to be able withstand roughly 300 F curing temperature for the carbon fiber.

Would a [high temp silicone gasket](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-High-Temp-Black-Silicone-Gasket/?N=5002385+3292638826&rt=rud) work?

Would it be able to withstand the temperature as well as roughly 50-100 psi of internal force from the bladder without separating?

Comment: I wouldn't risk a dramatic explosion. Why not silicone plus screws? Even if the adhesive held I wouldn't trust the wood to not delaminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krayden offers [**Loctite Hysol**](https://krayden.com/buy/brands/loctite-hysol/), a high heat epoxy suited for wood applications up to 350 degrees. They have other similar products with even higher heat ratings.
[image]

Here's some [**3M Scotch Weld Epoxy**](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/~/3M-Scotch-Weld-Epoxy-Adhesive-2214-Hi-Temp-New-Formula/?N=5002385%203291797505&rt=rud) as well
[image]